# How can I categorize properties of my control to appear in appropriate sections in Blend and Visual studio designer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-runtime, blend

In previous XAML technologies, you could add a `CategoryAttribute` to a dependency property and it will appear in the properties window of Blend and Visual Studio.

For example, I want to add a new `Brush` property to a custom control and have it appear under the "Appearance" category.

```
[Category("Appearance")]
public Brush MyAwesomeBrush { get {...} set {...} }
```

Is there a way to do this for Windows store apps (Win8/Win10/Phone/etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it if you really want to.

Add the following class to your project (keep the namespace, everything exactly this way):

```
namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
    public class CategoryAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public CategoryAttribute(string category)
        {
            Category = category;
        }

        public string Category { get; private set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == this)
                return true;

            var other = obj as CategoryAttribute;
            return other != null && other.Category == Category;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Category.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Use it this way:

[image: how to use it]

And tada.wav, it works :)

[image: blend screenshot]

Comment: Excellent! That works! What other attributes can we do this to?

Comment: Well I guess if Blend can be tricked into using this one, most of these'll probably work as well https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk67c2t8.aspx

Comment: Yes. `DescriptionAttribute` works as well. Same code as above. I'll try more.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c2792d7b-a35d-4c36-ac27-9696fd28742a#d6db9b91-471d-40ea-a317-ba6225671249) post, it's unsupported in Windows Store apps etc.